# query returning duplication's despite nested query returning no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query below which works. However it is return duplicates which I don't understand.

The first three nested queries return no duplicates so I don't understand why the end result has duplicates sedols?

```
 ;with b as
 (
    select sedol, wgt from myTbl
    where name = 'B'
 ), j as 
 (
    select sedol, wgt from myTbl
    where name = 'J'
 ), s as
 (
    select sedol, wgt from myTbl
    where name = 'S'
 ), hlds as
 (
    select coalesce(b.sedol, j.sedol, s.sedol) sedol, isnull(b.wgt,0) bw, isnull(j.wgt,0) jw, isnull(s.wgt,0) sw
    from b full outer join j on b.sedol = j.sedol
    full outer join s on b.sedol = s.sedol  
 )
 select hlds.* from hlds
 order by sedol
```

**sample data**

```
myTbl 

sedol    name   wgt
abc      b      1
abc      j      2
abc      s      3
def      j      2
def      s      4
```

current result

```
abc    1      2      3
def    0      2      0
def    0      0      4
```

should be

```
abc    1      2      3
def    0      2      4
```

Comment: Show sample data please.

Comment: Whenever you join two tables, a record from one side can appear multiple times for each time it matches a record on the other side.  Perhaps you might want to use a `UNION` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets improve this query and save the joins with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.sedol,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name = 'B' THEN t.wgt END) as [b],
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name = 'J' THEN t.wgt END) as [j],
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.name = 'S' THEN t.wgt END) as [s]
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.sedol
```

Comment: thanks very much! it works and its also much neater than my attempt. I thought maybe using the case's would make the query inefficient appears i was wrong

Comment: No problem, `CASE EXPRESSION` on given columns is actually very fast , especially if it saves unnecessary selects from the table.